# tidying data: grouping values and keeping dates

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Im begining with dplyr / tidyr package for data manipulation and reshaping.

```
city <- c("Brest", "Brest", "Rennes", "Rennes", "Rennes") 
year<- c(2014, 2015, 2013, 2012, 2016) 
values <- c(100, 100, 110, 95, 95) 

# Création du data.frame
dataset <- data.frame(city, year, values)  
dataset
```

Here is my dataset:

```
city    year    value
Brest   2014    100     
Brest   2015    100     
Rennes  2013    110     
Rennes  2012    95      
Rennes  2016    95
```

What I am doing:

```
demo <- dataset %>%
    count(city, values) %>%
    arrange(city)
```

...and my results:

```
 city   value  n. of obs
 Brest  100     2       
 Rennes 95      2       
 Rennes 110     1
```

What I expected to have:

First option :

```
  city   value  n. of obs      year
  Brest     100     2          2014, 2015
  Rennes    95      2          2012, 2016
  Rennes    110     1          2013
```

Second option :

```
  city   value  n. of obs   year1    year 2
  Brest     100     2       2014     2015
  Rennes    95      2       2012     2016
  Rennes    110     1       2013
```

Can I do this with adding mutate to my pipe?

Thank you for helping

Comment: With base R, `aggregate(year~city + values, dataset, function(x) c(year = toString(x), numberOfObs = length(x)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a group by operation and then `summarise` by `paste`ing the 'year' together (`toString` is a wrapper for `paste(..., collapse=", ")`)

```
dataset %>%
      group_by(city, values) %>%
      summarise(n = n(), year = toString(year))
```

Or if we want the second option, after the group by operation, create the number of rows (`n()`) and a sequence column by `paste`ing a string 'year' with the `row_number()` and then do the `spread` to convert it to 'wide' format

```
dataset %>% 
     group_by(city, values) %>% 
     mutate(n = n(), i1 = paste0("year", row_number()))  %>%
     spread(i1, year)
```

Comment: It works great  but not totally understand `i1 = paste0("year", row_number()))  %>%
     spread(i1, year)`

Comment: @Wilcar  I updated the post.  It is just to create a sequence column so that the rows will be unique for `spread` to process